# Put array-like object as template value argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I want to implement a

```
template<class ValueType,UnitTag x>
clsas Quantity;
```

With operators like

```
template<UnitTag y>
Quantity<T,x+y> operator*(Quantity<T,y> b)
    {return Quantity<T,x+y>(m_value*b.value());}
```

(it is also possible to add quantities, but only of the same kind)

Operations on `UnitTag`s has to be done element-wise

```
x_0 + y_0 = z_0
x_1 + y_1 = z_1
x_2 + y_2 = z_2
x_3 + y_3 = z_3
...
```

The most straight forward way would be to let `UnitTag` be a constexpr array. But that cannot be used as a template argument. As a workaround, I can do it with a large integer type, and use a small number of bits to represent each dimension. However, this gives a limitation on the number of dimensions, or the power of each dimension: For example, with 64 bits and 16 dimensions, I only covers [L^(-8), L^7]. This should be good for most applications, but the class cannot deal with radicals, since this requires fractional powers.

Is there any way to pass more than 64 bits of information in a template argument? For example, is it possible to do element-wise operations on a template parameter pack? The element-wise operations required are:

- addition (For multiplication)
- subtraction (For division)

For radicals:

- Division (This requires elements to behave like rational numbers. Can be implemented as a class using a `constexpr word()` accessor)

Answer (score 3):

I try to propose a solution according

> is it possible to do element-wise operations on a template parameter pack?

Not sure (I don't know what do you exactly want to do with this values) but if you wrap the template parameter pack in a `std::integer_sequence` (or a `std::index_sequence` if you can use a pack of `std::size_t`), it seems possible to me.

Unfortunately, `std::integer_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` are C++14 features. But if you need in C++11, it's easy to implement something similar.

The following it's an example using `std::index_sequence`

**-- EDIT --** Modified example adding subtraction/division

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename, typename>
struct addVI;

template <std::size_t ... Is, std::size_t ... Js>
struct addVI<std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::index_sequence<Js...>>
 {
   static_assert(sizeof...(Is) == sizeof...(Js), "! add");

   using type = std::index_sequence<(Is+Js)...>;
 };

template <typename, typename>
struct subVI;

template <std::size_t ... Is, std::size_t ... Js>
struct subVI<std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::index_sequence<Js...>>
 {
   static_assert(sizeof...(Is) == sizeof...(Js), "! sub");

   using type = std::index_sequence<(Is-Js)...>;
 };

template <typename, typename>
struct foo;

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
struct foo<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 {
   template <std::size_t ... Js>
   using Ks = typename addVI<std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                             std::index_sequence<Js...>>::type;

   template <std::size_t ... Js>
   using Ls = typename subVI<std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                             std::index_sequence<Js...>>::type;

   template <std::size_t ... Js>
   foo<T, Ks<Js...>> operator* (foo<T, std::index_sequence<Js...>> const & b)
    { return foo<T, Ks<Js...>>(); }

   template <std::size_t ... Js>
   foo<T, Ls<Js...>> operator/ (foo<T, std::index_sequence<Js...>> const & b)
    { return foo<T, Ls<Js...>>(); }

 };

int main ()
 {
   foo<int, std::index_sequence<1, 2, 3>> f1;
   foo<int, std::index_sequence<2, 3, 5>> f2;

   static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(f1*f2),
                              foo<int, std::index_sequence<3, 5, 8>>>::value,
                 "!!");

   static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(f2/f1),
                              foo<int, std::index_sequence<1, 1, 2>>>::value,
                 "!!!");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass several integer arguments.

As alternative, take a look into the book "C++ template metaprogramming" by Abrahams and Gurtovoy. They name this idea as "dimensional analysis" and use type lists for `UnitTag`.

```
typedef mpl::vector_c<int,0,1,0,0,0,0,0> length;
typedef mpl::vector_c<int,0,0,1,0,0,0,0> si_time;
...
typedef mpl::vector_c<int,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0> velocity;
...
```

The multiplication operator for tags `D1` and `D2` makes the type list

```
typename mpl::transform<D1,D2,mpl::plus<_1,_2> >::type
```